# Symfony command to edit Robots.txt

Tags: php, symfony, robots.txt

I'm writing a command that will on update my `robots.txt` file, i have some category pages with a little content, and i have a db flag public to show or not those pages, now i want to create a command that excludes automaticly these pages in `robots.txt` file.

My `robots.txt` is in web directorium. I created a commnand that runs on

```
sudo php app/console webmain:robot_excluded_category_command
```

And my command looks like this

```
class RobotExcludedJournalsCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('webmain:robot_excluded_category_command')
            ->setDescription('Exclude category in robots');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $container = $this->getContainer();
        new GFinderBundle($container->get('kernel'));
        $result = [];
        foreach (CategoryRepository::getAll() as $category) {
         if($category->getPublic() == 0){
                    $result [] = [
                        'id' => $category->getName()
                    ];
         }
        }
        ladybug_dump_die($result);

    }
```

In my `$result` i got all categories that should be excluded from `robots.txt`
for example names are (science, fitness, gaming, life...)

I need to add or edit this in `robots.txt` with my command

```
# Categories
User-agent: *
Disallow: /category/science
Disallow: /category/fitness
Disallow: /category/gaming
Disallow: /category/life
.
.
.
```

What is the best way to edit `robots.txt` file with symfony command, to check the list and `add/remove` `(update)` with latest changes that i get with my result?

Answer (score 4):

Consider it another way – don’t create the file, just have a route called `robots.txt`. So long as you return `text/plain` as the MIME type, it doesn’t matter if it’s a ‘real’ file or not.

Then you can just build a method to build the contents for you. Consider adding some sort of caching to prevent it overloading your application.

Something like this:

```
// if no cache {
    $robotsList = Robots::list();
// }

$response->setContent($robotsList);
$response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);

// sets a HTTP response header
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

// prints the HTTP headers followed by the content
$response->send();
```

Comment: And what do you think about  this in foreach
$RobotTxtFile = fopen($RobotDir, "w") ;
$txt = "Disallow: /category/".$category->getName()." \n";
The file will be overwritten every time the command is set, and this can also do the trick....

Comment: No need, you’re just adding complexity that’s not required. No need to worry about permissions or writing to a file.